# How to appear on the new local search carousel?

Tags: ranking, local-seo, google-ranking, google-local-search

Google have rolled out a [new layout for local search](http://blog.autorevo.com/2013/06/new-local-search-layout/) — a carousel:

[image: Google local carousel]

This is similar in appearance to the "frequently mentioned on the web" results which are based on [Google's knowledge graph](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/introducing-knowledge-graph-things-not.html) database.

Does this new layout affect [the guidelines on how to rank for local search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43757/how-to-get-ranked-for-local-search)?

Comment: It's no different then local search. It's just a different presentation.

Comment: @JohnConde, cool, thanks, that's what I thought — but you never know :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the carousel will make any difference for optimizing your local listing.

I think one needs to add high quality images of their business (may give additional benefits).

Comment: Adding rich snippets for reviews could also help CTR in this context